# Appending from Arraylist to StringBuilder Removes Newlines

Tags: java, arraylist

So i am writing a .ini (config files) writer and reader. There may be libraries available but i just want to try and do it myself. One problem i am running into is when i use FileWriter and try to add Elements from arraylist to file using get() function of arraylist and appending to file using append (). However that is not writing anything to file and ends up removing all content from the file.

As a alternative i am appending the arraylist to stringbuilder and then to using toString () to turn that into string but the appending of Arraylist to stringbuilder gets rid of newlines. The newlines are only at specific places so i cant just use \n at the end of every append. Is there a way to preserve those newlines?

This is the code being using to convert from arraylist to stringbuilder and then writing to file:

```
void WriteConfig() throws IOException {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file, false);
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

        for(int x = 0; x < lines.size(); x++) {
            System.out.println(lines.get(x));
            str.append(lines.get(x));
        }
        System.out.println(str.toString());
        fw.write(str.toString());

        fw.close();
    }
```

When adding the key-value pairs i am using \n however those just get ignored by StringBuilder.

Comment: It would be best to provide a [mre] demonstrating the problem, as well as sample inputs and outputs.

Comment: A `StringBuilder` will not just ignore newline characters. Something else must be wrong—see [mre]. For instance, how are you populating `lines`? Also note that `println` adds a line separator implicitly, so if you're wondering why you get different output to the console than the file that is at least one reason.